# Xamarin IOS development in visual studio - what to connect to

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.ios

I am doing Xamarin IOS development in visual studio, and have just learned that Xamarin Live Player does not work on the IPhone (all such links lead to only Android devices). So.. does anyone know what the minimum apple computer requirements are to be able to build IPhone apps on windows visual studio linked to a mac over the wire? Or.. Can someone point me to another way that I can build IPhone via Xamarin without purchasing such a apple computer? Feel free to redirect me to another site if this is not appropriate to post here - I figure its development related but its not a coding question so I didn't know where to post.

Comment: A simple Google search led me to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements

Comment: @CSharpRocks thank you. I wonder, though what the min hardware requirements are still, as this really only mentions the required OS.

Comment: On a budget? You can use an older model that you can buy second hand as long as it can run the minimum OS requirement for Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a virtual machine (VMWare, etc.) that runs MacOS. But you will be violating Apple's EULA which states that MacOS should only run on Apple's hardware.

Comment: And the minimun requeriments for run it is almost a machine with card graphic, 16 gigas of ram and intel core i5. But remember you will be violating Apple's EULA.